# Primeng Carousel does not get the correct style

Tags: angular, primeng

I have this copy of Primeng v8 carousel component but the result is very different than its web site:

```
<p-carousel dir="ltr" [value]="basicDataService.latestProducts"  [numVisible]="4">
    <ng-template let-product pTemplate="item">
        <div class="product-details">
            <div class="p-grid p-nogutter">
                <div class="p-col-12">
                    <img src="https://cdn.struffelproductions.com/file/cc0texturesimages/textures/Sphere/256/WoodFloor12.png" />
                </div>
                <div class="p-col-12 product-data">
                    <div class="product-title">{{product.name}}</div>
                    <div class="product-subtitle">{{product.description}}</div>

                    <div class="product-buttons">
                        <button pButton type="button" class="ui-button-secondary" ><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
                        <button pButton type="button" class="ui-button-secondary" ><i class="fa fa-star"></i></button>
                        <button pButton type="button" class="ui-button-secondary" ><i class="fa fa-cog"></i></button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </ng-template>
  </p-carousel>
```

and the result (the chevron buttons to navigate right and left are above the contents but in the original one the buttons are at the sides) is like this:
[image]

Comment: Seems you didn't include the primeng css in your application. See this: https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/setup

Comment: I did. But when I inspect the p-carousel item it does not contain ui-carousel-container item

Comment: Other primeng components that I have added are working correctly

Comment: The demo from the primeng website does include a bit of styling (CSS). Try adding that to your code, and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: I got the primeng project from github and removed all the styles but the view was totally different than this

Comment: same here, I can't get the latest carousel and its styling - I suspect its the theme.css that has changed? kindly update!

Answer (score 0):

You need to update primeng version to the latest to get the proper view.

- 8.1.1 is the stable proper version
- you can update it up-to PrimeNG 9.0.0-rc.4 on Angular 9.0.0-rc.10
- BUT those are rc versions.